# Way to divide a single background image across multiple divs to create "windowed" effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there is an easy way to "tile" or "window" a single background image across multiple divs.
I want to create a sort of punched out window look.

Keep in mind that I want to dynamically add these boxes. There will be a maximum of 16, but I could have 9.

I have a fiddle here: [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/22/)

What I want to do is instead of the background image showing, it would just be white.. And instead of the divs being white, they contain that section of the background image. Sorry if this is not a very good description, but basically I want to swap the white with the background.

so something like:

```
<div id="blocks">
  <div class="block" style=" background: some-section-of-image ;"></div>
  <div class="block" style=" background: some-section-of-image2;"></div>
  <div class="block" style=" background: some-section-of-image3;"></div>
  <div class="block" style=" background: some-section-of-image4;"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to do this with as little jQuery as possible... but maybe that is not feasible.

I fiddled around some with setting

```
opacity:0.0;
```

on just the blocks, but can't figure out how to not display the image elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: what else are you going to be displaying here?  anything else on top of this or inside the boxes?

Comment: Use `background-position`. You don't need JS at all, just CSS.

Comment: I want the background image in the boxes. I will probably put some text in them that appears on rollover.

Comment: I don't think I can use background-postion because I want to dynamically generate these.

Comment: This isn't what you're after is it? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bzCNb/23/

Comment: I was in the process of typing out a lengthy response until you said dynamically. You can still use the background-position. Once you set your pics, just use jquery's `.css()` or `.style()`. Even still, unless the background your using is different sizes, setting your background-position should still be good enough.

Comment: Saying you can't do something because something else is "dynamically-generated" just means to need to learn how to code it.

Comment: @j08691 background-size would work as long as he doesn't need to support older browsers.

Comment: Just to know if that's the way, because it still needs some work: http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/26/

Comment: Couldn't you just use a whole background image and place white borders on the dynamically generated divs?

Comment: uhm? [jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/31/](http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/31/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A CSS-only solution**

What you are describing is basically a table with a background image and white borders. A simple solution can be achieved by creating a table-like layout with CSS only.

```css
.blocks {
    display:table-row;
}

.block {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100px;
    border:15px solid #FFF;
}

#background-container { 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/2IqWvm5.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-container">
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>        
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I came into something that's nearly a 100%. Feel free (anyone) to edit the answer.

**CSS**

```
#blocks {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.block {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent url(http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0172.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

**jQuery (JS)**

```
$(function () {
    var posX = 0;
    var posY = 0;
    var i = 0;

    $(".block").each(function (ind, el) {
        $(this).css("background-position", posX.toString() + "% " + posY.toString() + "%");

        posX += 20;
        i++;

        if (i == 4) {
            i = 0;
            posX = 0;
            posY += 25;
        }
    });
});
```

Demo (to be improved): http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/33/

Comment: Yea I was fooling around in the elements inspector and check this out: [fiddle:jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/31/](http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/31/)

Comment: I see. I think it's just a detail missing, but after working on my own stuff all day long, I can't spot anything else right now.

Comment: No worries. I really like this kind of challenge. LOL

Comment: I think this is as good as I can get for now: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/36/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the question interesting and wondered how hard it would be to do this with vanilla JavaScript nowadays, for any tile shapes or positions.

Answer: it's not so hard.

Snippet below illustrates that with 3 different ways of laying out tiles for a tiled image, all handled by the same JavaScript code.

It works with the following algorithm:

1. find an element with class `tiled-image`. Use this frame's dimensions for image layout
2. find the first `<img>` element inside it: use it's `src` as tiled image. Remove it
3. For all elements with class `tile` inside it, find their position, set their `background` as the image, with `background-position` offset so it always matches the frame's upper-left, and `background-size` set to the frame's size

*Current limitation: the frame's size must match the image's aspect ratio. Could easily be improved for dynamic image sizes*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', _e=> {
  const tFrames = document.querySelectorAll('.tiled-image');//Find tiled frames
  tFrames.forEach(frame => {                                //For each one
    const img = frame.querySelector('img');                 //Retrieve first img
    if (!img || !img.src) return;
    img.remove();                                           //Remove it
    const src = img.src;                                    //Store its src
    const fBounds = frame.getBoundingClientRect();          //Store position of frame
    frame.querySelectorAll('.tile').forEach(tile => {       //For each tile
      tile.style.backgroundImage = `url('${src}')`;         //Set bg image to img's src
      const tBounds = tile.getBoundingClientRect();         //Find position
      //Position background to frame's upperleft corner
      const bx = tBounds.left - fBounds.left;
      const by = tBounds.top - fBounds.top;
      tile.style.backgroundPosition = `left ${-bx}px top ${-by}px`;
      //Set background size to frame's size
      tile.style.backgroundSize = `${fBounds.width}px ${fBounds.height}px`;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/*General positioning */

.tiled-image {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}

/* fallback to regular image if javascript doesn't run */
.tiled-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* DONE. The rest is decoration and specific tile positioning for the 3 examples */

body {
  background: linear-gradient(164deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(145,145,167,1) 35%, rgba(70,80,82,1) 100%);
}

.light-text {
  color: gainsboro;
}

.tiled-image + .tiled-image {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

/* debugging help */
/*
.tiled-image {
 outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.tiled-image .tile {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
*/

/* regular grid */

#ti-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* irregular grid */

#ti-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
            "a a c c c c"
            "b b c c c c"
            "b b d d e e"
            "b b d d e e";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
#ti-3 .ta { grid-area: a; }
#ti-3 .tb { grid-area: b; }
#ti-3 .tc { grid-area: c; }
#ti-3 .td { grid-area: d; }
#ti-3 .te { grid-area: e; }

/* position absolute */
#ti-2 { position: relative; }
#ti-2 .tile { position: absolute; }
#ti-2 .t0-0 {
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}
#ti-2 .t0-1 {
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  height: 400px;
}
#ti-2 .t0-2 {
  left: 410px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 510px;
}
#ti-2 .t1-0 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 220px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 380px;
}
#ti-2 .t1-1 {
  left: 180px;
  top: 420px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 170px;
}
#ti-2 .t1-2 {
  top: 560px;
  left: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="light-text">With regular grid</h4>
<div class="tiled-image" id="ti-1">
  <img src="http://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/800x600-Wallpapers/800x600-Wallpapers-048.jpg" />
  <div class="tile t0-0"></div>
  <div class="tile t0-1"></div>
  <div class="tile t0-2"></div>
  <div class="tile t1-0"></div>
  <div class="tile t1-1"></div>
  <div class="tile t1-2"></div>
  <div class="tile t2-0"></div>
  <div class="tile t2-1"></div>
  <div class="tile t2-2"></div>
</div>

<!-- DONE. Next examples use the same code with different numbers of tiles -->

<h4>With irregular grid</h4>
<div class="tiled-image" id="ti-3">
  <img src="http://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/800x600-Wallpapers/800x600-Wallpapers-042.jpg" />
  <div class="tile ta"></div>
  <div class="tile tb"></div>
  <div class="tile tc"></div>
  <div class="tile td"></div>
  <div class="tile te"></div>
</div>

<h4>With position: absolute</h4>
<div class="tiled-image" id="ti-2">
  <img src="http://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/800x600-Wallpapers/800x600-Wallpapers-047.jpg" />
  <div class="tile t0-0"></div>
  <div class="tile t0-1"></div>
  <div class="tile t0-2"></div>
  <div class="tile t1-0"></div>
  <div class="tile t1-1"></div>
  <div class="tile t1-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the background on the blocks instead of the page with fixed attachment and alignment of left top.  Unfortunately with this option if the page scrolls the background appears fixed.

```
.block{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0172.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/28/

Comment: Yea, I don't really want the background to be fixed like that. As in I don't want the image to scroll with the page.