# One Background Image, Multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am going to explain my question with a series of images.

A div container will have the following background image:

[image]

On top of the image, there will be tile like divs:

[image]

My goal is to make the background image visible to only the tiles, and the rest hidden: 
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I love it when people try so hard to avoid using <table>, that they do 10x the work to get a table.

Comment: The tiles would be responsive, so as the tiles reshaped, the background would be static. That why the tiles show one consistent image.

Comment: I guess this answers your question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768453/way-to-divide-a-single-background-image-across-multiple-divs-to-create-windowed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768453/way-to-divide-a-single-background-image-across-multiple-divs-to-create-windowed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the background-attachment attribute like in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1ovd3cnk/1/

each image block gets the following:

```
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOV15.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
```

edit: was setting margin on row instead of conatiner

Comment: Amazing. I was trying to point OP to background-clip, but couldn't make it work :D

Comment: Note that the background image will appear "shifted" depending on how far from the top left corner of the window the container is: http://jsfiddle.net/yo66c2gw/

Comment: Yes, this was to show how to use that attribute in getting the desired effect, not a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry reply like this, I don't have reputation enough to add comment in other comments, but making some adds to the earlier answer:

The image shifted could be fixed using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

But remember that `cover` property isn't supported in old browsers.
http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

So if you want cross old browser compatibility I recommend you to try javascript and do some maths using the width and height from your elements to adjust de background image position.